# Mapping canvas LinearGradient to an image

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas

```js
function show(d) {

   function  normalize(val, max, min) { return (val - min) / (max - min); } 

   var canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

   let width = canvas.width = 400;
   let height = canvas.height = 400;
   let arr = d //<-- 1D array of noise data, type: float

   let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(25, 25, width  - 50, 25);
   gradient.addColorStop(0,   "black");
   gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "red");
   gradient.addColorStop(1,   "lime");

   ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
   ctx.fillRect(25, 25, width  - 50, 25);

     function generate(end=false) {
       let w = 50, h = 50;
       let startx = (width/2) - (w/2);
       let starty = 85;
       ctx.clearRect(startx, starty, w, h);
       ctx.strokeRect(startx, starty, w, h);
       if (end) return;
       for (let i = 0; i < w; i++)
         for (let j = 0; j < h; j++) {
           let x = i + startx;
           let y = j + starty;
           let index = i + j * w;
           let val = arr[index]
           let color = colorAt(val).join(", ")
           ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${color})`;
           ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
         }
     }

     generate()

     function colorAt(t) {
       t = 25 + (350 * t);
       let pixel = ctx.getImageData(t, 35, 1, 1).data;
       return [...pixel];
     }

     canvas.id     = "CursorLayer";
     canvas.style.width = '600px'
     canvas.style.height = '600px'
     canvas.style.zIndex   = 8;
     canvas.style.position = "absolute";
     canvas.style.border   = "1px solid";
     document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 }

/* create noise */
let array = []; // <-- this array is allways going to have a length of 2500
function populate(w, h) {
  for (let i = 0; i < w * h; i++)
    array[i] = Math.random();
}
 populate(50, 50) 
 show(array)
```

I have mapped my data to `CanvasRenderingContext2D.createLinearGradient` using this code above.
`arr` is the data and it's a 1D array of float values of length 2500. The length is static I don't want to add more data to it

I'm currently able to output this image: [gradientImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf8fC.png)

How do I get rid of the gradient bar and make my desired image larger? without adding more data to the array

Comment: Could you make your code into a working snippet - it makes it much easier to follow what is going on. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplistic way of getting rid of the gradient bar across the top once it is no longer needed is to overwrite it with white when you have finished using it.

The size of the final image is set with w and h variables and this snippet increases them from 50 to 300 so the image is still within the canvas.

Here's your code as a runnable snippet. As I do not know how you set up arr I have removed use of that in comments and just used a color.

```js
function show(d) {

  function normalize(val, max, min) {
    return (val - min) / (max - min);
  }

  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

  let width = canvas.width = 400;
  let height = canvas.height = 400;
  //let arr = d.attributes.position //<-- 1D array of noise data, type: float

  let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(25, 25, width - 50, 25);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, "black");
  gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "red");
  gradient.addColorStop(.8, "lime");

  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillRect(25, 25, width - 50, 25);

  function generate(end = false) {
    //w and h made bigger
    let w = 300,
      h = 300;
    let startx = (width / 2) - (w / 2);
    let starty = 85;
    ctx.clearRect(startx, starty, w, h);
    ctx.strokeRect(startx, starty, w, h);
    if (end) return;
    for (let i = 0; i < w; i++)
      for (let j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        let x = i + startx;
        let y = j + starty;
        let index = i + j * w;
        //let val =  normalize(arr[index],255,0)
        //let color = colorAt(val).join(", ")
        ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(255,0,,0,1)`;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
      }
  }

  generate()

  function colorAt(t) {
    t = 25 + (350 * t);
    let pixel = ctx.getImageData(t, 35, 1, 1).data;
    return [...pixel];
  }

  canvas.id = "CursorLayer";
  canvas.style.width = '600px'
  canvas.style.height = '600px'
  canvas.style.zIndex = 8;
  canvas.style.position = "absolute";
  canvas.style.border = "1px solid";

  //ADDED   
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(25, 25, width - 50, 25);

  //END OF ADDED
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
}
show();
```

If this were mine I would probably want two canvases. One just temporary which will hold the gradient so you can look up the color at a particular position and the other where the final image will be painted and I'd make it fill the whole of that canvas.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to using canvas API how would I pass my final image to a new canvas?

Comment: You wouldnt pass it to a nwe canvas as such, you'd actually draw it on a canvas in the first place. i.e. you'd have two canvases, one for the color grid and the other for the picture. But I guess we are wandering into a different question.